# Canonical and Duplicate without user-selected canonical

Tags: search-engine-indexing, canonical-url

I manage a website made up of HTML pages (as oppose to PHP). There is a `.htaccess` file that:

- adds `www`
- adds `https`
- hides the `.html` extension

All of the current HTML pages have a line of code telling search engines which is the canonical page, for example:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.net/example-page">
```

However, the CMS we are using (Surreal) doesn't allow us to add this canonical link to new pages and in Google Search Console it appears that pages are being excluded from indexing because pages are "Duplicate without user-selected canonical."

If it helps: internal links use the url plus .html ending.

What can I do?

Comment: What CMS are you using?     What page does Google say is the duplicate?  Is it the version with the `.html` extension?

Comment: Hi. Surreal CMS. Yes I believe Google is saying that the version with the .html extension is a duplicate and is excluding both the .html and non .html versions

Comment: When you link to pages on your site, do the links have the `.html` extension in them?

Comment: I've edited the post as suggested. Thanks